# Save and Read meta box values from db

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a custom meta box. Everything works perfectly (saving values etc.). Now I would like to load this values from different posts and pages. For example: I created 3 inputs in post "A" and saved the post. After that, I want to load them to page "B" by choosing them in select input.

This is my code to print saved values in specific post/page:

```
$slide = get_post_meta($post->ID,'slide',true);
$i = 0;
if ( count( $slide ) > 0 ) {
    foreach((array) $slide as $option ) {
        if ( isset( $option['title'] ) || isset( $option['desc'] ) || isset( $option['img'] ) ) {
            printf( '<div class="insideslide"><table class="tableslide"><tbody><tr><td>Main title:</td><td><input type="text" name="slide[%1$s][title]" value="%2$s" /></td></tr><tr><td>Description:</td><td><input type="text" name="slide[%1$s][desc]" value="%3$s" /></td></tr><tr class="uploader"><td>Choose background:</td><td><input type="text" name="slide[%1$s][img]" class="slide[%1$s][img]" value="%4$s"> <input type="button" name="upload-btn" class="upload-btn button" value="Upload Image"></td></tr></tbody></table><input type="button" class="deletebutton button" value="Delete slide" /></div>', $i, $option['title'], $option['desc'], $option['img'] );
            $i = $i +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to start?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with populating a `<select>` field...Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing just this:

```
$all_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
```

Then you will have all meta variables in an array and you can use them in page B in any way you like.